# If the word "method" is abstract noun then why do people say "a method" with article?

Tags: articles, abstract-nouns

I learnt that "abstract nouns don't get articles". Now my question is if the word "**method**" is an *abstract noun* then why do [people](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%22a%20method%22&oq=%22a%20method%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.3779j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) say "**a** method" with an article? The same question for the noun "**wish**", which is referred as "**a** wish" ("You need a wish...").

Are they considered as mistakes or they are exceptions among other *abstract nouns* which get articles? If they are, is there an explanation for why they get articles?

Comment: The answer here is the same as your previous question on the same subject.  "**A** method" is not abstract.